# Retrieving entire list as text from BeautifulSoup.select

Tags: html, python-3.x, parsing, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

I'm trying to parse MLB data for a project I'm working on. I'm new to coding and trying to use beautiful soup. The code I've written is as follows. My problem is that after using `.select` I'm returned multiple html elements in list format but what I really need is the actual numbers inside these elements in list format. I've tried using various ways of retrieving the text but I keep getting errors saying that a list can't be returned as text. If I use 
`ABSoup[1].getText`, I can retrieve one value, but I can't figure out how to retrieve them all at once. I also tried using a function to iterate multiple times but I get an error with this also. Any advice or help to a new developer would be greatly appreciated!

```
import requests
import bs4
data = requests.get('http://www.baseball-reference.com/players/gl.fcgi?    id=harpebr03&t=b&year=2017')
MLBsoup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(data.text, 'html.parser')
ABSoup = MLBsoup.select('td[data-stat="AB"]')
print (ABSoup)
#[<td class="right " data-stat="AB">3</td>, <td class="right " data-stat="AB">4</td>, <td class="right " data-stat="AB">3</td>, <td class="right " data-stat="AB">4</td>, <td class="right " data-stat="AB">4</td>, <td class="right " data-stat="AB">4</td>, <td class="right " data-stat="AB">4</td>, <td class="right " data-stat="AB">2</td>, <td class="right " data-stat="AB">4</td>.....
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a small example how to reach it with using `find_all` and `text` as an argument in order to retrieve text only:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = (BeautifulSoup('<td class="right " data-stat="AB">3</td><td class="right " data-stat="AB">2</td>'))
print (soup.find_all(text=True))

>>> ['3', '2']
```

**EDIT:**

You can iterate the list from the select and parse it with BeautifulSoup.

```
text_results = []
for item in ABSoup;
  text_results.append(BeautifulSoup(item).find(text=True))
```

Comment: I'm not sure this would work as the tricky part is that the .select portion is returning a list hence the [ bracket at the beginning of the output(there's one at the end as well). It's the fact that this is a list that makes me unable to pass it back through Beautiful Soup.

Comment: Thank you for your help with that though. I was able to convert the list into a string using the following:

Comment: ABSoup = MLBsoup.select('td[data-stat="AB"]')
    AbSoup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(("".join(str(x) for x in ABSoup)), 'html.parser')
    print (AbSoup.find_all(text=True))